# Android Studio Google+ login

Tags: android, angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3

I don't now why this code stops running, I've put some flags it has been senseless. It just goes to the end of the code, and does nothing. There you have some of the code.

```
loginGoogle(){
this.googlePlus.login({
  'prompt':'consent',
  'hd':'go-labs.net',
        'webClientId': '660851996372-sou3k2to7661epk1a78mfid6hap105ne.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  'offline': true
})
 //the code just stop running here
.then(res =>{
  if(res.email.endsWith('@go-labs.net')){
    const googleCredential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider
        .credential(res.idToken);

    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential)
  .then(response => {
      this.dbUsers.addUser(response.uid, response.displayName, response.email);
      this.loading.dismiss().then(() => {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(PulperiaPage);
      });
    });
  }
  else{
    this.loading.dismiss().then(() => {
      this.googlePlus.disconnect().then(res => {
        this.presentAlert('That's not a valid account');
      }).catch(error => {

      });
  });
  }
  //and then run this
  }, err => {
    this.loading.dismiss().then(() => {
      this.presentAlert('Denied Access');
    });
  });
  this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create();
  this.loading.present();
```

}

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: No, there are no console error, it just doesn't run well

Comment: You must test this on the device.Are you?

Comment: Is happening the same thing.

Comment: See the console errors on a device running.

Comment: Nothing happens as well, only shows a message that is in the end of the code